# OpenGraph values

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm sorry, I have searched for a day and a half but I can't find the specific answer I'm looking for.

My Facebook Like button doesn't appear on IE, Chrome or Firefox.  I am using Javascript.

1. I  have the required HTML addition.
2. I need to put in the Meta Tag
   meta property="og:tag name" content="tag value"

   COULD I GET AN EXAMPLE FOR THE "TAG NAME" AND "TAG VALUE"?
   I don't know what to fill in!
3. I am supposed to have the Javascript SDK right after the body; however, I don't know what to put for an APP_ID as in:

   ```
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
     //CAN I GET AN EXAMPLE OF YOUR_APP_ID, please?
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
     //is channel.html the page it's on?
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
   // Additional initialization code here
    };
   // Load the SDK Asynchronously
   (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
   </script>
   ```

I am getting so frustrated!  Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The `YOUR_APP_ID` is the ID of your Facebook Application. If you haven't created a App, you can do so [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

However, you don't need to use an app to use the Like Button plugin. You should be able to use the Plugin just by copy-and-pasting the plugin code from the developer website. If that doesn't work, use the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you to read more carefully the documentation of the Facebook's JS SDK, but also the "Getting Started" and the "Core Concepts". There you will find a lot of very useful information.

I'll try to explain what the App_id is. When you want to do some more funcional applications, that interact with user information from facebook, you need to create a Facebook's app. To do that log into your account and go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps. There you need to tell your app's name, URL, and some other things. When you save you'll see an app_id, that is an unique number that identifies your app on Facebook. Is this number that you have to put in your script (surrounded by quotes, don't forget).

The channel file is a single line html file that you have to put in your server, at the same domain of your app. The content of this file is:

```
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Replace the "en_US" by your app locale.

You questioned about the meta tags of the OpenGraph. Well, when you click "like" for a URL, the Facebook-bot navigates to your page and reads the meta information. When it finds OpenGraph meta tags, the information posted at the user wall is more personalized. You'll have to spent a little time to understand more what kind of OpenGraph meta tags you will need, once every site has different information to share.